# Question about vinegar in expressions

Tags: meaning, context

What does "vinegar in her voice" mean? It was said by a girl in a story about her sister, she envies her and feels bad in some way. The story is from the Bible.

Comment: Have you tried looking up _vinegar_ in a dictionary? There is one definition that fits exactly and even (on dictionary.com at least) uses this exact phrasing as an example.

Comment: 'The story is Biblical' - can we have the book, chapter, verse, and translation?

Comment: *The Red Tent* is about someone in the Bible, Dinah, the daughter of Israel, nee Jacob, but it is not a Bible story and is nearly entirely made up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not real common, but definitely not unknown.  "Vinegar" is tart/acidic, and makes a person speak with a sort of scratchy voice.  But, more significantly, "vinegar", in one sense, implies a sourness of attitude, ie ill will.

So the person was speaking with a bad attitude, and you could almost hear it in the way she spoke.

Answer (score 1):

[Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/vinegar) quotes an unsourced reference relating to speech under their entry for 'vinegar' :

> sour or irritable speech, manner, or countenance:
> **a note of vinegar in his voice.**

I found two metaphoric references to vinegar in the Bible, both from Ecclesiastes, all other references being to actual vinegar :

> As vinegar to the teeth, and as smoke to the eyes, so is the sluggard to them that send him. Proverbs 10:26.
>
> As vinegar upon nitre, so is he that singeth songs to a heavy heart. Proverbs 25:20.